# 'resourceid cannot be empty' when approving API access in admin site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

In the SharePoint online admin center, I'm unable to approve API access for my SharePoint spfx app.
I keep getting this error: 'resourceid cannot be empty'

The app already works on another tenant. I am tenant and SharePoint admin.

Any idea's what I'm missing?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably another error. I suggest you try to approve with powershell, this will give you a better error message. I had the same issue, and the reason was that I missed one space in the resource name. With powershell, I got a better error message.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient#manage-permissions-with-powershell

Answer (score 2):

Above issue occur, if resource Id is not correct. When we define permission in Package.Json
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
{
"resource": "spfx",
"scope": "user_impersonation"
}
]

Resource means your Azure Active Directory instance name. It should match and scope should also be defined in that AAD instance.

Screen Shot FYR.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
I had a typo in the name of the 'resource' in the webparts package-solution.json.
It has to be the exact same name as your 'app registration' in Azure AD.

Both the answers of users Olga and user3519513 above helped me solve it.

```
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
      {
        "resource": "MyCorrectApplicationRegistrationName",
        "scope": "user_impersonation"
      },
      {
        "resource": "Windows Azure Active Directory",
        "scope": "User.Read"
      }
    ]
```